# How to delete all files from Dropbox via the web interface

Tags: dropbox

I want to delete all of my Dropbox files (before I delete my account).
I want them to be removed from any kind of history too.

But I have already uninstalled the Dropbox software from all devices.

How can I delete all files using just the web interface at dropbox.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now simpler than this.

On the Dropbox website, there are now checkboxes that appear when you move the mouse cursor over the top filename. Check the first box. This will cause all the top-level file checkboxes to be checked. Then choose delete.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to dropbox.com
2. Click on the top file, but not on its filename, rather on the whitespace near it. This will "select" the file.
3. Press your keyboard's SHIFT and then down arrow to "select" all folders/files
4. Click the *Delete* button that has appeared at step 2. Confirm.
5. Reload the page (because of a bug)
6. Repeat the selection, and press *Permanently delete*.

By doing this we can hope that Dropbox actually really deletes the files.